# Spark program to join two text files and store through Apache Phoenix spark plugin

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

I have two files where I should join the two records based on common key to create a single record

```
Record 1: 
key val1 val2 val3 val4

Record 2:
key val5 val6 val7
key val5 val8 val9

Output Record:
key val1 val2 val3 val4 val7 val9
```

val6 and val8 will be the column names that should create. For any subsequent keys, val6 and val8 might repeat.

I am trying to achieve above in spark- Data frames and store the resultant dataframe to Hbase through Apache Phoenix. My problem is how to make val 6 and val8 as columns in a RDD/Data Frame and then identify them for subsequent key?

I have thought of using join based on key, but I didn't understand how to make it as a column in a Data frame. Thanks for your help.